# Link to codeline with javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

Is it possible to create a link to a specific codeline (ankor) with javadoc.
I can link methods and classes of course, but I would like to link to specific codeline where a specific mehtod is called.

Is this possible in any way ?

Comment: Should this link really be part of the javadoc?

Comment: Must not be. But it should also not be only linenumber specific.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comment that this shouldnt be in the javadoc. the doc generated by the javadoc is supposed to be independent from code.

BUT

if you use eclipse then a file+line can be linked: `@link myFile.java:<<LINE>>`

This isn't part of the official javadoc specification though ;)